# How do I POST an array of KeyValuePairs to WCF Service in PHP?

Tags: php, wcf

here is the WCF service signature:

```
[OperationContract]
DataResponse PostData(string transactionKey, KeyValuePair<string, string>[] customFields);
```

I am using nusoap, but I believe that I have the freedom to use any PHP library. 
I'd like to know how to post the array in JSON or possibly XML.  I do not mind rendering the actual string and posting a string, if that works.

FYI: I am collecting the KeyValue pairs from Input elements and their values, so I do not have a custom KeyValuePair object or class to serialize.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to POST as json, just use `json_encode();`:

```
$some_array = array();
$some_array['first_name'] = 'john';
$some_array['last_name'] = 'doe';

echo json_encode($some_array); //send this out.
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.  I was hoping for sample code for using this with nusoap or soapclient.  currently, I am trying to just use curl to post xml to the service.  I am having difficulties